# Fancybox buttons are too small on mobile (non-responsive site)

Tags: javascript, android, fancybox, gallery, viewport

I use [Fancybox 3](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/3/) for my [gallery](http://www.vldesign.co.il/m/portfolio_en.htm).

Fancybox buttons (<, > ,x, caption) are very small on my android, my viewport is static:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=640">
```

I can't use 'width-device, initial-scale=1.0' because it's not responsive, and shows my site incorrectly so I need a solution for static (non-responsive) website..

Maybe there's something to do with the css/js files of this plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to **over-ride** the default styles provided by fancybox.

For example, to make the caption larger, you could use something like

```
@media (max-width: 800px)
.fancybox-caption {
    font-size: 35px;
}
```

To over-ride, make sure to include the above style *after* you have included jquery.fancybox.css

Comment: Thank you so much, you helped me alot!

Comment: You are welcome :) can you mark the answer as the right one if it worked for you.

Answer (score 1):

If you wish, you can easily scale all interface elements using CSS, for example:

```
.fancybox-infobar__body, .fancybox-button {
  transform: scale(1.5);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all, I changed them one by one with media query as Niket offered, works great, now I know that there's a shorter way too @Janis ... :-)

here's my css for anyone who wants to know:

```
@media all and (max-width: 800px) {
.fancybox-caption {
    line-height: 35px;
    font-size: 30px;
}
.fancybox-infobar__body {
    font-size: 30px;
    width: 120px;
    line-height: 60px;
    margin-left: 10px;
}
.fancybox-button {
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    line-height: 60px;
}
.fancybox-button--close::before, .fancybox-button--close::after {
    height: 3px;
    width: 30px;
    left: calc(50% - 15px);
}
```